# MPI_Scatter Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm trying to run quicksort using MPI, but the Scatter function is giving me an error.

```
double *v = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
if (mpi_rank == 0) {
    init_random_vector(n, v);
}
// n is the number of data items
int elements_per_proc = n/mpi_p;
double *sub_v = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*elements_per_proc);

if (mpi_rank == 0) {
    //insertion_sort(n, v);
    MPI_SCATTER(v, elements_per_proc, MPI_DOUBLE, sub_v, 
        elements_per_proc, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

I get a seg fault at MPI_Scatter. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Why are you calling `MPI_Scatter` in the root rank only? It is a collective call and all ranks in `MPI_COMM_WORLD` have to call it for it to complete successfully.

Comment: I didn't know that, although I have tried calling it with all processes but I still get a seg fault. @Hristolliev

Comment: Are you really calling `MPI_SCATTER` or `MPI_Scatter`? C is case-sensitive and `MPI_SCATTER` could be the name of the Fortran interface which expects other argument passing convention, hence the segfault.

Comment: I thought I was using "Scatter" instead of "SCATTER". Let me try it out and I'll let you know what happens. @Hristolliev